# Search JSON array for matching string and then work upward?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to search an Array for a matching team name and then work upward to get the data for an entire match, however I'm unsure how to do so. The JSON array looks like the following:

```
{
  "name": "English Premier League 2016/17",
  "rounds": [
    {
      "name": "Matchday 1",
      "matches": [
        {
          "date": "2017-05-21",
          "team1": {
            "key": "swansea",
            "name": "Swansea",
            "code": "SWA"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "westbrom",
            "name": "West Bromwich Albion",
            "code": "WBA"
          },
          "score1": 1,
          "score2": 2
          },
          {
          "date": "2017-05-21",
          "team1": {
            "key": "watford",
            "name": "Watford",
            "code": "WAT"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "mancity",
            "name": "Manchester City",
            "code": "MCI"
          },
          "score1": 2,
          "score2": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

At the moment, my code is as follows, however it says it can't read property 'team1' of undefined.

```
var team = Swansea;

$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatajson/football.json/master/2016-17/en.1.json", function(results) { 
       for(var i = 0; i < results.rounds.length; i++)
        {
          if(results.rounds[matchday].matches[i].team1.name == team)
          {
            console.log(results.rounds[matchday].matches.team1.name);
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: (results.rounds[matchday].matches[i].team1.name == team) what is matchday assigned to @Josh

Comment: Matchday is a var defined earlier to help sort through the data. In the full one (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatajson/football.json/master/2016-17/en.1.json) each team turns up 38 times, so I first work out which matchday, then within the matchday I check that name for the team I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var team = Swansea;

$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatajson/football.json/master/2016-17/en.1.json", function(results) { 
       for(var i = 0; i < results.rounds.length; i++){
            if(i == matchday){
                for (var j=0; j< results.rounds[matchday].matches.length; j++){
                     if(results.rounds[matchday].matches[j].team1.name == team){
                        console.log(results.rounds[i].matches[j].team1.name);
console.log(results.rounds[i].matches[j].date);
                     }
                  }
            }

        }
```

Since you have the matchday assigned to some particular variable, you dont want to go in and loop through all the matches.
You can check if the iterator i and matchday are equal and then look for the team

Comment: How can I then use this to step back up and gather date, team1, team2, score1 and score2 from this entry?

Comment: @JoshCawthorne since you are already inside the matched team object you can just get date by matches[j].date

Comment: @JoshCawthorne same way you can get all the other values by matches[j].(any key)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @JoshCawthorne was my answer helpful or solved your problem

Comment: Updated to show it's solved, however can't upvote as I'm below 15 rep :P

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
var team = Swansea;

$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatajson/football.json/master/2016-17/en.1.json", function(results) { 
       for(var i = 0; i < results.rounds.length; i++)
        {
          for (var j=0; j< results.rounds[i].matches.length; j++){
             if(results.rounds[i].matches[j].team1.name == team)
             {
                console.log(results.rounds[i].matches[j].team1.name);
             } 
             if (results.rounds[i].matches[j].team2.name == team){
                console.log(results.rounds[i].matches[j].team2.name);
             }
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Getting "Uncaught TypeError: results.rounds[matchday].find  is not a function" on this code? EDIT: Please disregard this, it's a different broken solution I accidentally left in while testing; the solution WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

I just add console.log() when find team name. You can put your logic on there.

```
var team = Swansea; 

$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatajson/football.json/master/2016-17/en.1.json", function(results) { 
           results.rounds.forEach(round=>{
                Object.keys(round).forEach(key=>{
                    if(key.contains('team')){
                         if (round[key].name === team){
                              console.log('Team identified.');
                         }
                    }
                })
           })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of all matches containing your team:

```
var team = 'Manchester United';

$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatajson/football.json/master/2016-17/en.1.json", (results) => {
    let matches = [];
    results.rounds.forEach(round => {
        matches = matches.concat(round.matches.filter(match => {
            return (match.team1.name === team || (match.team2.name === team))
        }));
    });

    console.log(matches);
})
```

(I changed `team` to Manchester United, assumed 'Swansea' was an unintended bug.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However as a Leeds fan, I can assure you it wasn't a bug.